# Проблемы с изменением свойств объектов в Firemonkey

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!

Есть программа, при старте подключается к БД. Использую firemonkey. Подключение происходит в отдельном потоке, что бы основной не ждал в случае неудачного (долгого) подключения. После удачного подключения в процедуре `TSQLConnection` - `SQLConnection1AfterConnect` происходит изменение текста `label` на "В сети" и создание `GlowEffect`'а который помещается в контейнер `label`'а и изменяется цвет на зелёный.

Фантастика начинается в процедуре `SQLConnection1AfterConnect`.
Иногда текст `label`'а не меняется, иногда не создаётся `GlowEffect`, иногда `GowEffect` создаётся, но без зелёного цвета, иногда создаётся с зелёным цветом (как надо).
Но после того как я делаю `Hide`, а потом `Show` этого окна то всё становится как надо! `Label` меняет текст на правильный, цвет `GlowEffect`'а становится тем какой нужен.

Просто не понимаю, как это здесь устроено и что происходит. Событие окна `OnShow` пропало...

```
procedure TForm1.SQLConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
    label1.Text:='В сети';
    ConnectionGlowEffect:= TGlowEffect.Create(Form1);
    ConnectionGlowEffect.Parent:=label1;
    (label1.Children[1] AS TGlowEffect).GlowColor:=claChartreuse;
    (label1.Children[1] AS TGlowEffect).Enabled:=true;
end;
```

Comment: магия портовой обезьянки

Comment: можете достать XE3 и посмотреть, как там обстоят дела. Говорят, там много чего пофиксили, особенно в FireMonkey

Comment: Помог вызов SQLConnection1.Open из потока через процедуру Synchronize(). НО! Если не использовать потоки и всё вызывать последовательно, то возникает ошибка ACCESS VIOLATION! Выглядит как будто объект еще не создан! Если добавить проверку "if assigned(ConnectionGlowEffect)", то возвращает FALSE.....

Comment: В delphi XE3 beta если использовать второй поток работает и с синхронизацией и без. А вот если последовательно всё вызывать то опять же не работает, правда ошибка теперь другая - исключительная ситуация "argument out of range". Возникает при попытке изменить цвет свечения.

Answer (score 1):

Форма не до конца инициализирована, к моменту работы с Label. Начинайте работу когда окно показано, если хотите эффектов и фаершоу.